# c++ declaration error with classes

Tags: c++

I have a structure `info` with several functions. One of these function is `info combineInfo` and takes in two arguments (two sets of info).

```
Info combineInfo(info1, info2);
```

In `main` I input everything into info1 and info2 with a constructor and all is well with those. However, I'm running into a dead end when calling `combineInfo(info1, info2)` from `main`. I am recieving the message "error: `combineInfo` was not declared in this scope."

```
Info info1; //this is from a constructor that inputs all the values from cin.
Info info2; // ^^
Info3 =  combineInfo(info1, info2;
info3.printinfo(); // constructor from class, works fine.
```

The function looks like this:

```
Info Info::combineInfo(Info1, Info2); // sets some values of info1 to info3 and some of info2 to info3.
```

Comment: give the code snippet where the error occurs, including the struct/class definitions

Comment: It is much easier to post the code along with the compilation error, than to describe the problem with so many words.

Comment: @Nawaz -- I don't feel it's appropriate to post 500+ lines of code. I will add some more details thanks.

Comment: You could just post the relevant code, the declarations at least. And the error messages are not usually 500+ lines.

Comment: Is `combineInfo` a non-static member function of `info`?

Comment: @PatrickNommensen so make a short code that describes the problem

Comment: where is `combineInfo` defined?

Comment: Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). It's not just about posting code for us to see. Quite often, preparing a minimal example still demonstrating the bug can lead you to a solution.

Comment: Is `Info3` declared as an object, a type or not at all?

Comment: `Info combineInfo(info1, info2);` does NOT make sense to me!

Comment: @Nawaz it is Info3 :-)

Comment: @Aniket -- it's defined below `main` and declared in the class.

Answer (score 1):

The function should be:

```
  class Info{
    static Info combineInfo(Info info1, Info info2) { 
      //implementation  
    }
    //the rest of the class implementation!
  };
```

And since it is a member function, it needs scope resolution operator `::`.

`info3 = Info::combineInfo(info1, info2);` and this is how you call it!

The current implementation you have expects `combineInfo` to be in global scope, while it is inside a class(a member function) - hence the error!

Comment: makes sense, just that there is no objects here according to build messages. (when not using static)

Comment: If you can post the code of `combineInfo` we can solve this problem! @PatrickNommensen

Answer (score 0):

Use 
Info::combineInfo(info1, info2);

you cannot access Member functions outside directly. you need to use scope resolution operator :: or . to access it.